# How to automate my three bash scripts over several folders with files?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have a large number of files, and each file is going to be decoded, sorted/minimized and then put in a database. Each of those operations have its own bash script. The files are sorted into daily files, which are is in their consecutively monthly folders. The problem is that there is only one database, with one table (SQLite), so the database script can only run at one file at the time, while the decoding and sorting can be done at about four files at the same time.

For a file to be sorted, it has to been through the decode process, for a file to be put into database, it has to be decoded and sorted. The running time of these scripts are not the same, I believe the decoding is the fasting, then comes the inputing then comes the sorting.

Each bash script `decode.sh` `sort.sh` `saveintodb.sh` loops through all the files in the folder and does its works.

Originally I thought to have a masterscript which executes `decode.sh`-> `sort.sh`-> `saveintodb.sh`
for each folder(month).

However, as this is expected to take several days, I thought of something like this:

```
1: decode.sh January
2: sort.sh January,       decode.sh February
3: saveintodb.sh January  sort.sh February        decode.sh March
4:                        saveintodb.sh February  sort.sh March     decode.sh April
```

etc.. up to december.

However, I have no idea on how I set this up, In a good way. I know I can run the scripts in `2:` in parallell, however I am not so sure how I would run the scripts 3: automatically when 2: is done.

I am also unsure if this is the best way to do it. Ideally there is a decoding script, a sorting script and a saveintodb script running at all time. Maybe even several decoding and sorting scripts (dunno if this will speed up the process, I'm working out of an external HD sadly).

**Data volume:** 1.3 TB

**Data type:** Text files

**Background:** Positional reports (latitude/longitude, time)

Sorry for this long text, any suggestions?

Comment: Is this some amateur hobby, or is it professional work? In other words, how serious are you? If it is for work, you are in trouble!

Comment: Somewhat serious, but I have a limit on hardware/money and on time, so I have to make due with my laptop and external HD sadly.

Comment: How would a full screw up cost to you? Imagine losing the laptop and the disk? What about your own time?

Comment: Good point. I may be looking into doing this on a cloud computing setup to prevent any harm to the equipment and data. However I got a real concern about safety.

Comment: For safety: think carefully about your scripts. Add several logging messages. Check them daily.

Comment: Please **edit your question to improve it** and tell the motivation and what is all this thing about (e.g. the kind & volume of data). If this is a bit serious your laptop+external disk+sqlite approach is a huge mistake, and you'll surely lose all data (and some hardware). External disks (and laptop) are not designed to run 24H/24

Comment: Even if you are a starving student doing this for your thesis, you should invest a bit of your money (and a lot of your efforts).

Comment: I have edited my question, and have looked into opening a droplet at Digital Ocean, where I will transfer my data. If you had the time and motivation, I would greatly appreciate an outline to a script that can run this operation as outlined in my question.

Answer (score 5):

On Linux, use a [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) to schedule your various shell scripts. They could run in parallel.

You might also look into [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/), but I guess you don't need it.

At last, a shell script could schedule another one using [at](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uat.htm) or `batch`. For example, `decode.sh`  might perhaps end with `batch -f sort.sh` or `at -f sort.sh now + 10 minutes`

And you might use some more powerful scripting language, e.g. Python, Guile, Perl, ....

BTW;, be sure to test success of every script (and even parts inside them). Use [logger(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) to emit log messages (perhaps after every step or command which lasts more than half an a hour, and at start and end of every script). Check daily the logs!

At last, I don't understand why only one database script can run at a time. Most real DBMS (PostGreSQL, MonGoDB, MariaDB, etc...) - but not sqlite - can run (or be configured to run) several database clients concurrently accessing the same database (or of course different ones). Read more about [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) properties.

Doing that on some external USB hard disk is IMHO a mistake, because such hardware has limited reliability (and is often slow). You should consider having some server (perhaps a good desktop might have such a role). You might need an [UPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply) to avoid power glitches.

If this complex processing and the processed data has some value to you, you should upgrade both the hardware (get a server machine, possibly with an UPS and [ECC RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECC_memory) and, if the data fits, an [SSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive)) and the software (use real DBMS, care for failure). Estimate the cost of failure and/or data loss (remember to take into account your time). Perhaps renting some cloud computing or storage could be interesting (or simply a [VPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) hosted Linux system with backup, you can get one for about two dozens of dollars or euros every month: [kimsufi](https://www.kimsufi.com/), [ovh](https://www.ovh.com/), [rackspace](http://www.rackspace.com/), [aws](http://aws.amazon.com), ...)...

Comment: Thank you! I have a SQLite database, but as I am writing into one table, I believe the database get locked, and it is not possible to input several files at the same time?

Comment: You should use a real DBMS (not sqlite). They are able to manage concurrent writes to a single table... (provided the database schema and indexes are designed carefully for that). Your overall setup looks fragile. If such processing is important to you, upgrade your hardware & your software. Estimate the cost of a failure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I really get where you are coming from, and what you are saying, but sadly I am under the limit of a budget thats outside my control, so I am afraid that I cannot upgrade my hardware at least.

Comment: Cloud things - or just renting a real VPS, cost a few dozens of dollars or euros per month.

Answer (score 2):

You could have two scripts, one that has a for loop and decodes and sorts and creates a file used as a flag by the other script.
The other script would check for those files in a while loop and put them into the data base as they come.
Script 1

```
function decodeAndSort{
      decode.sh $1
      sort.sh $1
      touch ./tmpDir/$1
}
for month in months
do
    decodeAndSort $month &  # the ampersand is to run in the background
done
```

Script 2

```
 array=bla #with names of files
 while [[ $count -lt 12 ]]
 do
    if [[ -e ./tmpDir/${array[$count]} ]] #test file exists
          saveintodb.sh ${array[$count]}
          rm ./tmpDir/${array[$count]}    # clear the flag
          (( count++ ))
    else
        sleep 1 # adjust this as necesary
    fi
 done
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
doit() {
  sem --id decode decode.sh $1
  sem --id sort sort.sh $1
  sem --id dbsave saveintodb.sh $1
}
export -f doit
parallel -j4 doit {} ::: Jan Feb Mar ...
```

This will make sure you run a single decode, sort and saveintodb at a time. If you only want to protect saveintodb:

```
doit() {
  decode.sh $1
  sort.sh $1
  sem --id dbsave saveintodb.sh $1
}
export -f doit
parallel -j4 doit {} ::: Jan Feb Mar ...
```

Here you will have 4 decodes/sorts running but only a single saveintodb.

`sem` is part of GNU Parallel.

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to. It can often replace a `for` loop.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel